# Can I run sharepoint 2007 native report viewer in synchonous mode?

Tags: firewall, sharepoint-2007, ssrs

We are hosting a SharePoint MOSS 2007 environment and installed and use the [Native Report Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159772.aspx) with SSRS 2005. All works fine from the LAN, but from internet, the report viewer displayes a page not found exception. As it turns out, the report is rendered in an iframe. The URL of this iframe is requested by the browser of the visitor. However, the report server is not accessible from the internet and we do not want to make it accessible.

In some ASP.Net applications, we use [another version of the report viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24932) and this will not render a iframe, but will embed the report in the page's mark-up. What's more, the report will be obtained from the report server by the web server and the report server is not accessible from the internet.

I have read about [synchronous rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252090%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in this version and hope to find a way to make the SharePoint version to behave the same way.

Does anyone know if this can be done, or some other way to allow the report server to remain well hidden behind the firewall?